# Outdoor carpet over trex decking in screen room

Tags: flooring

I have an enclosed room that has a Trex decking on the floor currently. I would like to put outdoor carpet in the room over the tracks decking and was wondering do I need to put some form of barrier or pad underneath the carpet on top of it on top of the tracks, the floor is open beneath to the exterior

Answer (score 2):

If it's outdoor carpet and you don't mind the fact that you'll have visible lines due to the edge profile and gap on the Trex, there's no reason you can't put it directly over.

It will land somewhere on the spectrum between deck and actual room, which is where it's already living, as described; it will just shift a little bit. If you want to shift it further along that spectrum, you'll need to consider something under the carpet to span the gaps, suited to how well the room is keeping weather off it.